# Jmeter test fail on same app different servers (Spring webflow + Primefaces)

Tags: jmeter, spring-webflow

I'm having a weird problem with JMeter.

Scenario:

- Web app running on localhost
- Record a simple test on Jmeter (login +  1 search)
- Execute the test on localhost with Jmeter. Test runs OK.
- Change the server and port on HTTP Request Defaul for another server's IP and port running the same version of the app.
- The test runs but fails at the search with ".FlowExecutionRestorationFailureException: A problem occurred restoring the flow execution with key 'e3s2'"

If i do the same swapging servers (record on remote server and try to execute on local) the behavior is the same.

¿Any clues of what can it be? I don't understand why it manages to do the login and navigate on another server but fails on other action.

In short, if I record a test it fails at somepoint if I change the server.

- Software_
- Jmter 2.12
- Primefaces 5.0
- Spring Webflow 2.3.1.RELEASE
- Apache Tomcat 7.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My expectation is that there is at least one dynamic parameter which is currently being hardcoded into your script. I would suggest to do the following:

1. Record your login+search flow once again
2. Inspect 2 .jmx scripts to detect any differences (i.e. one or more parameters having different values)
3. Once you find those problematic parameters you'll need to look into server's response body/headers/cookies/ to see where it lives.
4. As soon as you know where the parameter value lives you can use one of the following PostProcessors:

   - [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor)
   - [XPath Extractor](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0)
   - [CSS/JQuery Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS/JQuery_Extractor)

The whole process is called "correlation" so you can use "JMeter correlation" as a search term if above information is not enough to resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was some xhtml components that didn't had any specified Id so jsf would set something like id="mainForm:j_idt12". Since my test don't need to work on dynamic generated html (are simple tests) setting the ids solve the poblem.